# How to convert Json format to Python format with appropriate types instead of values

Tags: python, json, pytest

Can you please advice some library / any other tool or python code to convert Json format to Python format with appropriate types instead of values

Given (JSON format):

```
 {
        "data": {
            "id": 8,
            "email": "ajent.j@mail.com",
            "first_name": "Agent",
            "last_name": "J",
            "avatar": "image.jpg"
        },
        "support": {
            "url": "https://test.com/#support-heading",
            "text": "I’m an agent, but I’m from the future!"
        }
    }
```

Expected (Python format + types instead of values):

```
{
        "data": {
            "id": int,
            "email": str,
            "first_name": str,
            "last_name": str,
            "avatar": str,
        },
        "support": {
            "url": str,
            "text": str,
        }
    }
```

Comment: What earthly good is that?  You can certainly do it by iterating through the structure and doing `data[k] = type(v)`, but what purpose does that serve?  How will you handle lists and nested structs?  Why wouldn't `"support"` be `dict`?

Comment: I need such structure as an input for https://pypi.org/project/pytest-voluptuous/

Comment: So, is this a one-time thing?  Because there is certainly no point in generating a validation script on the fly.  The whole POINT of doing validation is to validate against a known, fixed structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fixing the mistakes in your JSON, this does what you asked.  Note that this does not handle arbitrarily deep nesting; if you have nested objects, then  first you have to decide whether you want to use `"dict"` or dive into them.  If you do want to dive into them, then you'd need to make this recursive.

```
import json
data = '''
{
    "data": {
        "id": 8,
        "email": "ajent.j@mail.com",
        "first_name": "Agent",
        "last_name": "J",
        "avatar": "image.jpg"
    },
    "support": {
        "url": "https://test.com/#support-heading",
        "text": "I'm an agent, but I'm from the future!"
    }
}'''

data = json.loads(data)
for k,v in data.items():
    for k1,v1 in v.items():
        v[k1] = type(v1)

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
{'data': {'avatar': <class 'str'>,
          'email': <class 'str'>,
          'first_name': <class 'str'>,
          'id': <class 'int'>,
          'last_name': <class 'str'>},
 'support': {'text': <class 'str'>, 'url': <class 'str'>}}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using VSCode you can use the [Paste JSON as Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype) extension.

Simply install the extension then type `Ctrl+Shift+P` (`Cmd+Shift+P` on MacOS) and type "Paste JSON as Code".

The Python code will be generated based on your clipboard contents.

Comment: Great extension, thank you!